# Differential Equations - Solving Inequalities using the Integrating Factor

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Suppose $y(1) = 0$ and $xy'(x)+2y(x) \geq 3x$ for all $x > 0$. How can I show them that $y(x) \geq x - 1/x^2$ for all $x\geq 1$?

I know how to find the general solution and the particular solution for $y(1)=0$ but it seems quite strange with the inequality.  How would I go about doing this question that involves inequalities? Is it the same method as if the equation had an "$=$" sign?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

***Hint***

$$xy'(x)+2y(x) \geq 3x \,\,\, \forall x>0$$

Since $x>0$
$$x^2y'(x)+2xy(x) \geq 3x^2 $$
$$(x^2y)' \geq 3x^2 $$
$$x^2y \geq \int 3x^2=x^3+K \,\,\, \forall x>0$$
Since $x>0$
$$y \geq x+\frac K {x^2}$$
$$y(1)=0 \to 0 \geq 1+K \to K \leq -1$$
$$....$$

Comment: Ahhh ok, would I then just integrate both sides?

Comment: if $f>g$ on $[a,b]$ then $\int f > \int g $ on $[a,b]$   you can divide by x the equation since $x \neq 0$